# Distinguish between key events from multiple keyboards

Tags: java, keyboard, glfw

I have GLFW setup to receive key events using

```
glfwSetKeyCallback(window, (long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) -> {
  // do something
});
```

This is all great, but I want to have multiple (2+) keyboards connected to one system and need to know which key event came from which keyboard. This will be used in a local-coop game.

*Can I distinguish between events from multiple connected keyboards? If so, how? Can GLFW handle this, or do I need any other library (I am using LWJGL for Java)?*

Answer (score 0):

Based on this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/827) from GLFW which was opened 4 days ago it seems there is no support for multiple keyboards yet. All searches point to this [article](https://nanlee.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/manykeyboard-using-java-hid-api-to-handle-multiple-keyboard-input/). There library uses HID API via its Java implementation.